# Mat Dialog Error in Angular Component ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material with Angular 6 where it is like on ngOnInit I have to display content if condition is correct.

I have Dialog Module using which I am displaying Dialog

```
  `if (!this.checkforRestriction()) {
  this.loadContent(this.ReferenceID);
} else {
  this.dialogService.okmessage('', dialogMessage);
}`
```

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'id: undefined'. Current value: 'id: mat-dialog-0'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
    at viewDebugError (core.js:8445)

I am getting this error.
Kindly suggest what is wrong ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's causing the problem without knowing a lot of details about all the invoked functions. However,  ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError can most likely be fixed by doing the following:

- try moving the code into ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook,
- try wrapping the code inside the setTimeout.

Finally, read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error). It should give you a better idea about the error you are facing.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks! Same problem here. setTimeout worked like a charm!

Comment: Adding to the answer: I moved my code to the constructor and it worked as well. You have to be careful to not do too much inside the constructor.

Comment: The link is broken now :(. Please update if you got anything new.

Comment: updated the link :)

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this same underlying issue with the following error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'aria-labelledby: null'. Current
>   value: 'aria-labelledby: mat-dialog-title-0'."

My dialog contains this directive for the title:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ model.title }}</h1>
```

Angular tries to apply the `aria-labelledby` attribute to the parent container of my dialog's component (mat-dialog-container). It isn't able to do so if you're opening the dialog in the callback from an http load.

In my case I was opening the dialog as part of an RxJS 'pipe' and adding `delay(0)` after the http get was effectively doing a 'setTimeout'.

eg.

```
const result = this.http.get(...).pipe(
                                       delay(0), 
                                       switchMap(response => {

   if (response.hasOverdueLibraryBook) {

       return this.dialogManager.openOverdueLibraryBookDialog();  // this is a mat-dialog
   }
   else 
   {
      return of(false);
   }

});
```